# Issue in IE7 tbar row seperator using extjs

Tags: html, internet-explorer, extjs, internet-explorer-7, extjs3

I need a component in next row of a top bar.I coded like this ,

```
tbar: [{
    xtype: 'textfield'
    id:'fname'
},'-',{
    xtype: 'textfield'
    ,id: 'lname'
},'<row>',{
    xtype: 'textfield'
    ,id:'mob'
}]
```

this is working fine in chrome,firefox and ie7+ browsers,but this is not working in ie7.can someone please correct my code.

Answer (score 0):

you have no comma after your xtype: 'textfield'.

IE7 is very comma sensitive in JavaScript.

```
tbar: [{
    xtype: 'textfield'
    ,id:'fname'
},'-',{
    xtype: 'textfield'
    ,id: 'lname'
},'<row>',{
    xtype: 'textfield'
    ,id:'mob'
}]
```

Edit: I made this fiddle, it works in all browsers:

http://jsfiddle.net/MG3fS/3/

Answer (score 0):

What about a very primitive approach?

```
tbar : {
    layout : 'auto', // im not sure why 'vbox' does not work here
    width: 200,
    items : [{
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: 'hbox',
        items : [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            id:'fname'
        }, {
            xtype: 'container',
            html: '-',
            width: 5
        }, {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            id: 'lname'
        }]
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        id : 'mob'
    }]
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error "Cannot read property 'ownerCt' of undefined" while using this approach.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I have left a typo in cfg of last component. xtype was 'texfield' instead of 'textfield'. Edit: seems there was also unnecessary comma as well.
Fixed now (though I am not sure whether it was causing your error)